# How to find the Height and Width of newly created element in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a custom tooltip element. I need the height and width of the new created tooltip element. I am always getting offsetHeight and offsetWidth as 0.

```
    var tooltip = angular.element('<div ng-style="tooltipStyle"><div class="ng-tooltip-arrow"></div>\n{{content}}</div>');
    tooltip.attr({
          'class': 'ng-tooltip ' + scope.theme + ' ' + scope.direction
    });
    var tooltipElem = $compile(tooltip)(scope);
    var height = tooltipElem[0].offsetHeight;    <!-- This is always 0 -->
    element.hover(function () {
        element.after(tooltipElem);
    }, function () {
        tooltipElem.remove();
    });
```

Comment: Maybe show some more context? Is the tooltip rendered on the DOM at this point?

Comment: yes. tooltip is getting rendered on DOM. IS issues arises at placement of tooltip. that's why i need the width and height of the tooltip, that is created.

Answer (score 0):

Very tricky, but is possible!

After compile, wrap it again around angular element:

```
    var $tooltipElem = angular.element(tooltipElem)[0];
```

And then obtain height and width:

```
    var height = $tooltipElem.clientHeight;
    var width  = $tooltipElem.clientWidth;
```

By the way, at the end, if you want to set the tooltip position, you can do this way:

```
    tooltipElem.css({
           top: top+'px',
           left: left+'px'
    });
```

Full working example: https://codepen.io/vsmori/pen/GORZdQ